# Error at snapshotData.docs[index].data()['firstName'] flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

- I am trying to implement `Searchbar` for my application which will search according to user's `firstName`.
- I am facing the below error saying

```
The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

[image]

- Code

```
late QuerySnapshot snapshotData;
..
..
title: Text(snapshotData.docs[index].data()['firstName'], style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 24.0
          ),
          ),
```

Comment: Check This : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254952/flutter-null-safety-the-method-cant-be-unconditionally-invoked-because-th

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Text(snapshotData.docs[index].get('firstName'))
```